# Error running InventoryActivityTes...: Cannot find runner for InventoryActivityTes

Tags: android

When I try to Run 'InventoryActivityTest' with Coverage.
This error will occur.

I tried InstrumentationTestRunner and AndoridJUnitRunner,
but it still not working.
While TestClass testing working well. How can I fix it?
If my description has any problem, tell me, please.

"gradlew createDebugCoverageReport" I tried. Below Message is Error StackTrace.

```
Unable to install F:\DDH\PhonePos\phonePOS\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all
        at com.android.ddmlib.SplitApkInstaller.install(SplitApkInstaller.java:91)
        at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackages(Device.java:901)
        at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:119)
        at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:121)
        at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:48)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
                                               
com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice > runTests[S300 - 5.1] FAILED 
        com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Failed to install all
                at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackages(ConnectedDevice.java:129)
                                               
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.       
                                               
* What went wrong:                             
Could not receive a message from the daemon.   
                                               
* Try:                                         
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Building 98% > :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
```